Cache problems in a vercel implementation with next13
I am generating some xml files with the rss library and using the getServerSideProps in next13, what happens I have established this rule
 res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, s-maxage=1800, max-age=1800");
Before, with 2 hours and limited to only 20 items, it was working without problems, vercel went to hit and did not launch the request again to create this file, but now I have gone down to 30 minutes and removed the limit on the articles and it stopped working, Logically it could be the weight but the file only weighs 210kb, which if it is too long that is to say it has a lot of text, I don't know if anyone has had this problem and how they were able to solve it and thanks in advance.
cache working in vercel
